# 400 Bad request while consuming a rest service with POST method?

Tags: mule4

I'm getting http requestor connection problem with POST:request a bad request even though I'm configuring properly. I'm sending json payload in the body and Bearer token in headers parameters with content type, I can evaluate the token and payload properly but still getting as a bad request when I tried to hit the direct URL as well, and I tried the trigger in postman with the same token generated in mule where I'm getting the success response but while using the same service within mule getting as bad request, I'm using http connector plugin version 1.7.1 in pom.xml.. Is there any problem with the dependency? can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are successful doing the request in postman then the HTTP request in your Mule application has to need some adjustments to make it match the postman request. Compare them carefully to make them match.

Comment: Can you help me with the what kind of adjustments should match exactly, I'm using the same rest service details in my property file and properly configuring the headers as well.

Comment: @KalyanSubrahmanyam You can enable http debug logs, and compare the exact request you are sending vs the postman one.

Comment: Your question doesn't contains any kind of details so the answer can only have the same level. If you want something more specific please provide all details of the request in postman and HTTP request and configuration from the mule application. As @HarshankBansal said enabling HTTP wire logging will be very helpful to compare with the raw request from postman.